# PhpMyAdmin throws Fatal Error isUserType() on a non-object at start. Blank Page displayed

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can use PhpMyAdmin normally when I set `$cfg['ServerDefault']` to `1`, my localhost. But I need the user to be presented with a list of possible servers.

When I switch `$cfg['ServerDefault']`  to `0` though PhpMyadmin doesn't load anymore. Blank page is displayed and error log shows following message:

```
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isUserType() on a non-object in /htdocs/libraries/Menu.class.php on line 511
```

What could be the Problem with this?

Comment: I'm just cruious what the downvotes were for? I get that my formatting should have been different i try to remember that next time. But what was the second downvote about? It is not a question i could find any information about even after extensive googling and searching through stackoverflow. There are many things which are slightly simmilar or have simmilar efects but nothing which is actually my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug...
Fixed with https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/99aad2c118c5af026bc17c60e615f62429d51816 or next version upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. Finally a right answer. This is true. New version fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user needs to have superuser privileges to be able to choose the server.  Here is the function in `Menu.class.php` that the error references:

```
 /**
 * Returns the server tabs as an array
 *
 * @return array Data for generating server tabs
 */
private function _getServerTabs()
{
    $is_superuser = isset($GLOBALS['dbi']) && $GLOBALS['dbi']->isSuperuser();
    $isCreateOrGrantUser = $GLOBALS['dbi']->isUserType('grant')
        || $GLOBALS['dbi']->isUserType('create');
    $binary_logs = null;
    $notDrizzle = ! defined('PMA_DRIZZLE')
        || (defined('PMA_DRIZZLE') && ! PMA_DRIZZLE);
    if (isset($GLOBALS['dbi']) && $notDrizzle) {
        if (PMA_Util::cacheExists('binary_logs')) {
            $binary_logs = PMA_Util::cacheGet('binary_logs');
        } else {
            $binary_logs = $GLOBALS['dbi']->fetchResult(
                'SHOW MASTER LOGS',
                'Log_name',
                null,
                null,
                PMA_DatabaseInterface::QUERY_STORE
            );
            PMA_Util::cacheSet('binary_logs', $binary_logs);
        }
    }
```

The bool `$is_superuser` needs to be `true` in order to access the server tabs array.  If you request the page as the root user it should work.

Comment: I sadly don't have root on this machine. So i can't test this. But this can't be the design of the application that this webservice needs to be run as root. Also didn't read anything about that necessity in the documentation. Isn't there a way to use this feature without having root rights?

Comment: Try going to /phpMyAdmin/setup and click "add server".  From there fill in the details of one of the servers you want the user to be able to select from.  Under the "Server Configuration" tab check the box for "Allow Root"

Comment: This is already set for all the Servers that i have added. Doesn't change anything